# C# Numeric textbox Shows exception after changing language From "En-Us" to Any global language in Control panel

Tags: c#, localization, type-conversion, numeric-textbox

I created an application which contains two numeric textboxes to which I've added an `StartValue` property.

#### Example

```
public decimal SValue {
  get { return MValue; }
  set { MValue = value; }
}
```

then

```
const string VALUE = "1.000";
private NumericTextBox sVal;
```

Problem comes here

```
sVal.StartValue = Convert.ToDecimal(VALUE);
```

After I change the language in Control panel from `EN-US` to any global language my application hangs.

Comment: Because for some culture it is comma instead of the decimal which is the seprator and when you use Convert it relies on the current culture, suggest using a Parse with an invariant culture option

Comment: Sir how to solve this..If i put Current culture in my thread also it shows... Can u help me in this

Comment: I meant try something like `decimal.Parse(VALUE,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Why use a `string` as the `VALUE`? Why not just use a `decimal` to start with and avoid the need to Convert/Parse it?

Comment: @  V4Vendetta Thanks sir... Problem solved.. :)